# is it possible define parameterized list in preprocessor

Tags: c++

Is there a way to define parametrized list using `#define` directive?

I mean something like this

```
#define List<T> std::list<T>
```

I don't want to use line `using namespace std;` and use simplified versions via preprocessor instead.

Or should I create separate definition for `List` (like `StringList`)? Or something like `List<String>` if possible?

Comment: #define List std::list should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `typedef` instead of macro:

```
template <typename T>
using List = std::list<T>;
```

Comment: There's no `typedef` in there, but yeah, still this. :)

Comment: Oh! Forgot completely about templates. Got this error `two or more data types in declaration of 'type name'`

Comment: It's one word, `typename`.

Comment: Definitely the best approach. Although, strictly speaking, you did not answer the question.

Comment: Well...The problem was that I forgot semicolon after last line.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Isn't this the age-old debate on how to answer "Should I drive in a nail with a glass bottle, or an old shoe?" questions?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: If I had just done a comment, you would complain that it should have been an answer ;-)

Comment: @Angew: Pretty much. This answer would IMO be better if it started off with the text "`#define List std::list` BUT instead you should:"

Comment: @Jarod42: Indeed! I didn't say it should be a comment :)

Comment: But `#define List std::list` was given as a comment under my post.

Comment: @user1432980: Right, which it shouldn't have been, because the comments section is for requesting clarification, not giving answers. That information should be moved to the _answer_ section. I can't believe I have to keep explaining to people how a bloody Q&A database works!!!